# Rake rules to generate multiple targets from single source/dependency

Tags: ruby, rake

I have a Rakefile as follows -

```
src_files = Rake::FileList["*.src"]
dst_files = src_files.ext 'dst'

task :default => dst_files

rule '.dst' => '.src' do |task|
  sh "cmd -o #{task.name} -i #{task.source}"
end
```

This Rakefile can find all .src files and generate corresponding .dst files.

Now,
From list of `.src` files say `file_a.src, file_b.src, file_c.src`, I want -

- `file_a.src` to create `file_a.dst` (works with current rule)
- `file_b.src` to create `file_b.dst` (works with current rule)
- `file_c.src` to create `file_c1.dst, file_c2.dst` and `file_c3.dst` (?!)

**Question is -**

How can I write rules to create files `file_c<n>.dst` from `file_c.src`?

-- where, n is array of numbers.

Comment: Update: I learned that there is no direct support for writing rule having multiple targets (reference: http://hyperpolyglot.org/build). But I kind of feel there should be a way to do it...

Comment: watch this talk by Jim Weirich,   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaEqZtulOus  it shows some pretty neat tricks do with Rake..

Comment: @Doon, Thanks. 'Power Rake'!? :) Nice presentation by Jim as always. And now I understand difference between file task and rules - and that one should keep rules very simple and rather use file tasks for anything more complex than having different extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a rule for it?
You may try to create multiple file tasks for it:

```
n = 1..6   #Your n-Array

n.each do |i|
  targetfile = 'file_c%i.dst' % i                 #Define the file to be created
  desc 'Create %s based n %s' % [ targetfile, 'file_c.src']
  file  targetfile => 'file_c.src' do |task|      #Define task to create targetfile
    puts "cmd1 -o #{task.name} -i #{task.source}" #Command to create targetfile
  end
end
```

In my tests I had no problem to combine it with the already defined rule.

Below my complete testcode:

```
require 'rake'
src_files = Rake::FileList["*.src"]
dst_files = src_files.ext 'dst'

task :default => dst_files

def build_dst(dst, src)
  puts "cmd -o #{dst} -i #{src}" #Command to create targetfile
  File.open(dst,'w'){|f|}        #Dummy to simulate generation
end  

rule '.dst' => '.src' do |task|
  build_dst task.name, task.source
end

N = 1..6  #array of numbers.

N.each do |i|
  targetfile = 'file_c%i.dst' % i            #Define the file to be created
  desc 'Create %s based n %s' % [ targetfile, 'file_c.src']
  file  targetfile => 'file_c.src' do |task| #Define task to create targetfile
    build_dst task.name, task.source
  end
end

#Make dummy-sources.
File.open('file_c.src','w'){|f|}
File.open('x.src','w'){|f|}

Rake.application['x.dst'].invoke
Rake.application['file_c3.dst'].invoke
```

You will see, the commands are exectuted as expected:

```
cmd -o x.dst -i x.src
cmd -o file_c3.dst -i file_c.src
```

---

One addition - out of the scope of your question:
I have some problems to see a real use case of your question.

If the command to generate `file_c<n>.dst` depends only on the same sourcecode, then the generated dst-files would be the same - you could just copy the result. I would expect some other differences in dependecies.

If your `file_c<n>.dst` depends an `file_c<n>.src` and `file_c.src` then you could use something like:

```
require 'rake'

rule '.dst' => '.src' do |task|
  puts "cmd -o #{task.name} -i #{task.prerequisites}" #Command to create targetfile
  File.open(task.name,'w'){}        #Dummy to simulate generation
end

#Add additional prerequsites (cold also defined generic)
file 'file_c3.dst' => 'file_c.src'

#Make dummy-sources.
#~ File.open('file_c.src','w'){|f|}
#~ File.open('file_c3.src','w'){|f|}

Rake.application['file_c3.dst'].invoke
```

I add additional prerequisites and replaced `task.source` by `task.prerequisites`.

Comment: this is precisely I wanted to move ahead. On top of this I can just say `task :variants => Rake::FileList['file_c1.dst', 'file_c2.dst', 'file_c4.dst']
` to create more variants of file_c.dst. I ran the code, it works.

Comment: about real use case - I am trying to create a Verilog source code here from a template by passing various arguments/parameters to the template processor along with template file and this template is nothing but a .src.

Comment: I went through https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KaEqZtulOus as pointed out to by @Doon and realized file task is a better solution since it is easier to understand, implement and debug - as mentioned by Jim in the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok with using `sh`, you can use this command to copy `file_c.src` to `file_c1.dst`, `file_c2.dst` and `file_c3.dst`:

```
cat file_c.src | tee file_c{1,2,3}.dst
```

Comment: this is a nice trick. What I am looking for is a real task/rule where I can do my stuff. Thanks..